# Unable to Import Modules in CodeSandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, codesandbox

This has happened multiple times with me recently. If I try to import a module in the codesandbox, even though it appears in the dependencies list, I keep seeing an error on the import line that:

```
Cannot find module 'react-redux'.ts(2307)
```

```
Cannot find module 'react-router-dom'.
```

```
Cannot find module 'redux-persist/integration/react'.ts(2307)
```

etc etc..
Why does this happen? Is it that the codesandbox does not support these yet?

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shape-q2kz0?file=/login.ts

Comment: Looks like an issue with typescript and how it tries to find import. See this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: Happens some times, hard resetting the window might help. By the way it's working fine for me